# Complex integration of real poles of multiplicity 2

Tags: integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I want to calculate the integral

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \dfrac{1}{(z^2-a^2)^2} \dfrac{1}{(z-a)^2+b^2} $$

where $a$ and $b$ are real, positive numbers.

The poles are at $z=a$ (multiplicity 2), $z=-a$ (multiplicity 2), and $z=a \pm ib$. When plotting these on the complex plane, the $z=\pm a$ poles sit on the real axis. I have two questions:

- I'm not sure how to draw the closed semicircle contour to enclose the poles on the upper/lower part of the complex plane. Do they include the $z=\pm a$ poles or not?
- How do I deal with the multiplicity of the $z=\pm a$ poles? I'm familiar with residue theorem but don't know how to deal with multiplicity greater than 1.

Comment: How do you even interpret the problem? (The integral clearly diverges.)

Comment: @ metamorphy. Could you please expand on your comment as an answer below? When you say that the "integral clearly diverges", is it because the $1/(z^2-a^2)^2$ has vertical asymptotes at $z=\pm a$? I assume it's this part that causes problems, even if it's multiplied with a smooth and well-behaved function (eg. lorentzian, Gaussian).